# Add 1 month to date for each cell that equals n

Tags: excel, date, time

I am trying to make a payment sheet, where if cell D2 equals 3000 it adds one month to a date in cell F4. But if cell D4 also equals 3000 it adds another month to the date in cell F4.

So that everytime I enter 3000 into D2, D4, D6 or D8 and so on, it adds one month to the date in cell F4. Get what I'm saying?

So example. D2 has a log that the 3000 was payed. This will add one month to the date 08-20-2015 to make it 09-20-2015. 09-20-2015 swings around and I add 3000 into D4. This will now add 1 month to the previous date of 09-20-2015 to make it 10-20-2015.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I indeed do not get what you are saying.  Would you mind asking the question a bit clearer?

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring it out. What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a formula that should do the trick:

```
=EDATE(F4,(SUM(IF(MOD(COLUMN(3:3),2)=0,3:3,0))/3000))
```

Instead of pressing enter to confirm the formula, use CTRL + ALT + ENTER as it is an array formula.

This sums every other cell in row D, then divides by 3000 and adds that number of months to your date.

Comment: Ended up using the below formula to get it to work on my sheet.

=ArrayFormula(EDATE(K2,(SUM(IF(MOD(COLUMN(D8:D100),2)=0,D8:D100,0))/3000)))

Does just as you said it would. Takes every other cell between D8 and D100 and adds the amounts in them. Then divides by 3000 and adds that amount to the date from K2 and displays it in the cell this formula is in. Thanks!